# Google JWT token validation on server side

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I have a React front end retreiving Google JWT token and sending it a a Back end (Sprinb Boot / GraphQl) server. Backend server is configured as OAuth2 resource server.
Server works correctly and calls google API.

But my problem is that is server may have restrictions and moved in an area where it cannot call Google API and only receive calls from its Front end.

So how can I check Google JWT token without calling Google ?
I only need to ensure JWT token is correct. Authorisations are handled seperatly.